# Event Handler not receiving event Laravel

Tags: laravel, events, notifications, listener, laravel-5.4

I am with L5.4 working on notification system. I have created events & listeners. I do have a test route for firing  this event. Event is fired successfully and I can even recieve it using `Pusher` in my blade views.

But for some reason I have to stop within `handle(NewUser $event)` method of my `listener`. I tried `dd($event)` But it never stops there. Although I have registered events and listeners mapping within my `EventServiceProvider` with `listen` property

```
//App/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php
 protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\NewUser' => [
            'App\Listeners\NewUserAdminNotification',
        ],
    ];
```

Actually, I want to store a `notification` in my database within that `handle` method of listener. But It never enters that method.

Any pointer to the problems are highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the listener code and how you're firing and testing it?

Comment: @Sandeesh, Thanks for your reply. See my comment on Jono's answer. As I already mentioned that event firing was ok but just handler was not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the notation for events & listeners classes works for me.

```
//App/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php

 protected $listen = [
        \App\Events\NewUser::class => [
            \App\Listeners\NewUserAdminNotification::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to clear the compiled classes to get Laravel to register the new events.

In console/terminal run:

`composer dump-autoload`

and

`php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried using a different notation in `EventServiceProvider` for both events & listener in `listen` array `\App\Events\NewUser::class` rather than string notation and It worked. I don't know why because even laravel docs mentioned the string notation.

Comment: Secondly, As you suggested about clearing the compiled classes with `dump-autoload` . Yes sometimes this works.  I think `laravel` automatically executes this command after we run `artisan make` command.